# Change grid column value from null to string empty

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on ASP.Net Core MVC app with [Telerik Kendo Grid](https://www.telerik.com/aspnet-core-ui/grid)

On the grid I have columns like:

```
 columns.Bound(x => x.PrimaryContact.EmailAddress)
              .ClientTemplate("#= PrimaryContact ? PrimaryContact.EmailAddress : '' #")
```

It works, but now the property `EmailAddress` inside PrimaryContact is showing the value "null" instead empty space, i.e: if PrimaryContact is not null but the property EmailAddress inside it is null, it displays it as a null. How can I solve that?
Can I add something to the `.ClientTemplate`? or is it possible to replace all null values for empty space on the jquery?

Current jquery:

```
  function onDataBound(e) {
            const grid = this;
            grid.table.find("tr").each(function () {
                const dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
                const text = dataItem.IsActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';

                if (dataItem.IsActive) {
                  //code here
                }
                else {
                  //code here
                }
            });
```

**UPDATE**

I access the property as:

const test = dataItem.PrimaryContact.EmailAddressNumber;

```
 if (test === null)
    {
      dataItem.PrimaryContact.EmailAddress.val = "";
    }
```

The console returns the 3 values I want to change but I can not replace them, as you can see I tried accessing .val property but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Finally found how to achieve this, you need to iterate table rows as:

```
const rows = e.sender.tbody.children();

for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  const row = $(rows[i]);
  const dt = e.sender.dataItem(row);
  const emailAddress = dt.get("PrimaryContact.EmailAddress");
  if (emailAddress === null) {
    row[0].cells[4].innerHTML ="";
  }
}
```

Hopefully, it helps someone